# White edge when orienting dark colored view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am just playing with an iPhone test app that orients the view when the simulator is rotated left or right. Everything worked fine when my view had a white background, however when I altered the view background to a darker color I noticed a white edge (1 pixel) around the view as it rotates. Has anyone come across this before or know how I might get rid of it. Indeed it might be an issue with the simulator that won't show on the actual device, but I just thought it worth asking for future reference.

gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen something similar before..

Go through the nib (.xib) files and make sure that all of the views have an appropriate dark background colour set, most notably the nib file which contains the "window". Click on them and set the background colour.

Comment: Hi Mobs, this was indeed the answer, the MainWindow.xib was set to white and there must be a fraction of a second delay between the views as they rotate. When I changed the BG color of MainWindow.xib to match my darker view the problem went away. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've never noticed it but then again I've never tried to rotate a very dark view. There might be a small border to keep the view from visually bleeding into the status bars or other views.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation and scaling in the discrete domain( as against analog) is quite difficult, because after a rotation/scaling the rotated location may not be a pixel location. You can suppress the effect by smoothening the edges, but I believe that is not implemented, and so the bug.